# Keyboard - Next button for website

Tags: android, jquery, html

In android app when we specify "actionNext", keyboard comes up with "Next" button which is useful when user has to fill a long form.

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

When user access the website from mobile, is it possible to replicate the same functionality with html5.